# get data from json string response in c# desktop app

Tags: c#, windows

I have response from server as for multiple students name

```
{"ENVELOPE":{"STUDENTLIST":{"STUDENT":["John","HHH"]}}}
```

or for single student name

```
{"ENVELOPE":{"STUDENTLIST":{"STUDENT":"John"}}}
```

and if error is there

```
{"RESPONSE":{"LINEERROR":"Could not find Students"}}
```

From these responses i want array of students name if no error else string with error i.e. string[] names = {"John","HHH"} or string[] names = {"John"} else string error =  "Could not find Students";

i tried as

```
 JObject jObj = JObject.Parse(responseFromServer);
 var msgProperty = jObj.Property("ENVELOPE");
 var respProperty = jObj.Property("RESPONSE");

 //check if property exists
 if (msgProperty != null)
 {
     var mag = msgProperty.Value;
     Console.WriteLine("has Student : " + mag);
     /*  
     need logic here :/ */
 }                
 else if (respProperty != null)
 {
     Console.WriteLine("no Students");
 }
 else
 {
      Console.WriteLine("Error while getting students");                    
 }
```

hope you got this..

Comment: So what is the question? Also you receive a JSON but load the responce in XMLDocument. Why?

Comment: @AzzyElvul actually response is in xml and converted that xml to json in application thats y XMLDocument used..

Comment: @AzzyElvul i just want students name in array from that converted json string if data is there else error message in string

Comment: If the response is xml, there is no need to use json in your code. Can you provide the XML responses instead? They probably make more sense than the json.

Comment: @JessedeWit please consider response in  json. see  edited question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally I would recommend to [deserialize](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DeserializeObject.htm) your object in a model, but since the `STUDENT` property is sometimes an array and sometimes a string, this is unfortunately rather cumbersome. I would recommend to [deserialize](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.deserialize?view=netframework-4.7.2) the actual xml you are receiving, because I expect the xml model to be easier to process.

In the meantime, this would work:

```
string input = "{\"ENVELOPE\":{\"STUDENTLIST\":{\"STUDENT\":[\"John\",\"HHH\"]}}}";
// string input = "{\"ENVELOPE\":{\"STUDENTLIST\":{\"STUDENT\":\"John\"}}}";
// string input = "{\"RESPONSE\":{\"LINEERROR\":\"Could not find Students\"}}";

JObject jObj = JObject.Parse(input);
if (jObj["RESPONSE"] != null)
{
    string error = jObj["RESPONSE"]["LINEERROR"].ToString();
    Console.WriteLine($"Error: {error}");

    // or throw an exception
    return;
}

var studentNames = new List<string>();

// If there is no error, there should be a student property.
var students = jObj["ENVELOPE"]["STUDENTLIST"]["STUDENT"];
if (students is JArray)
{
    // If the student property is an array, add all names to the list.
    var studentArray = students as JArray;
    studentNames.AddRange(studentArray.Select(s => s.ToString()));
}
else
{
    // If student property is a string, add that to the list.
    studentNames.Add(students.ToString());
}

foreach (var student in studentNames)
{
    // Doing something with the names.
    Console.WriteLine(student);
}
```

Comment: why not define a proper model and `deserialize`?

Comment: @Aarif That would be the way to go, but the STUDENT property is sometimes an array, sometimes a string, that would get messy and would need a custom `JsonConverter`. That was why I was asking for the xml, which may have a more logical data structure.

Comment: @JessedeWit yes response can have only one string or an array too... BTW thank you Sir... still now above code working for me...